# Alter CSS with JS based on even or odd number of class

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am learning css-grids and JavaScript. I wonder if it's possible to change the grid-template-columns minmax value of the :last-of-type element based upon if there are even or odd number of divs with that class. I cloned an example of grid layouts from Juan Martín García in a css-tricks article.

This is the HTML:

```
<section class="breweries" id="breweries">
    <ul id="cardContainer">
      <li class="card">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489993360877-883980cc7333?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="Several hands holding beer glasses">
          <figcaption><h3>Billions upon billions</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>
          Made in the interiors of collapsing stars star stuff harvesting star light venture billions upon billions Drake Equation brain is the seed of intelligence?
        </p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
      </li>
      <li class="card">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455620611406-966ca6889d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1430&q=80" alt="Several friends doing a toast">
          <figcaption><h3>Drake Equation</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>
          Another world citizens of distant epochs from which we spring descended from astronomers Orion's sword shores of the cosmic ocean.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
      </li>
      <li class="card">
        <figure>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460627390041-532a28402358?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="Three different glasses of beer">
          <figcaption><h3>Vast cosmic arena</h3></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>
          Galaxies the ash of stellar alchemy prime number science inconspicuous motes of rock and gas brain is the seed of intelligence.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

This is the CSS:

```
/* breweries styles */
.breweries {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.breweries > ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.breweries > ul > li {
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure {
  max-height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: .5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure > figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  width: 100%;
}

.breweries > ul > li > figure > figcaption > h3 {
  color: white;
  padding: .75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.breweries > ul > li > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1rem .75rem;
  color: #666666;
}

.breweries > ul > li > a {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

With the rule `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));` For the .cardContainer if the screen width goes down to 1055px, the last of the .card li element with a width of 350px will have 350px left of trailing space left on its right side.

I would like with JavaScript to first check if there are odd or even number of .card elements, and if there are a odd number of .card elements, change the width of the last .card element with :last-of-type, and set it so it takes upp all available space left in .cardContainer ul element.

This is my JavaScript:

```
let parent = document.getElementById("cardContainer");
let nodesSameClass = parent.getElementsByClassName("card");
console.log(nodesSameClass.length);

function isEven(card) {
    if (card%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

So this is how far I have managed to take it. I would like to understand how I can alter the else statement if it returns false and there are a odd number of .card li elements. So I can fill up the remains space and that last .card element fills up all available space in the .cardContainer ul element.

Comment: You know of this?
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Can do it with css alone if combine with `:nth-child(odd)` selector

Comment: ...That's a wide monitor (10555px)...

Comment: :P I meant 1055px

Comment: @charlietfl didnt know about that :) Thanks, I would still lite to solve it with javascript if possible for the reason that I do want to learn more js :)

Comment: I did try out the :nth-child(odd) but that would also effect the first element, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll`, it will return all the HTML elements which your selector points at and then grab the last one on the `NodeList`

```
const allCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const lastCard = allCards[allCards.length - 1];

lastCard.style.gridTemplateColumns = "whatever you need it to be"
```

Comment: It's important to notice that the order of the elements in the nodelist (type `NodeList`) has the elements in the order that they appear in the DOM